# Move the last 2 bytes of a 4 byte field?

Tags: cobol

I need to move the two bytes of a four byte field into a new field that is two bytes.

Code I want to use:

```
MOVE C-SERVICE-CYE TO S-CYE.
```

I need the last two digits of the year.  Ex: 2014 would be 14

Data Structure:

```
02  S-DATE.                            
     10  S-MME   PIC X(02).             
     10  FILLER  PIC X(01) VALUE '/'.   
     10  S-DDE   PIC X(02).             
     10  FILLER  PIC X(01) VALUE '/'.   
     10  S-CYE   PIC X(02).
```

Second Data Structure:

```
02  C-SERVICE-DATE-E.             
    10  C-SERVICE-CYE   PIC X(04).
    10  C-SERVICE-MME   PIC X(02).
    10  C-SERVICE-DDE   PIC X(02).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two fairly straight forward ways of doing this.

One is to subdivide the source variable declaration:

```
02  C-SERVICE-DATE-E.             
    10  C-SERVICE-CYE.
        15 C-SERVICE-CYE-CC PIC X(02).
        15 C-SERVICE-CYE-YY PIC X(02).
    10  C-SERVICE-MME   PIC X(02).
    10  C-SERVICE-DDE   PIC X(02).
```

Then modify the MOVE statement to: `MOVE C-SERVICE-CYE-YY TO S-CYE`

The other way is to use reference modification: `MOVE C-SERVICE-CYE (3:2) TO S-CYE`

This all works because the data items you are referencing here are `DISPLAY` types. Had they
been numeric (eg. COMP something) this technique would not work.

Comment: Both are good answers. i never can figure out how to pick the best answer for the points to be awarded. Difficult at best.

Comment: @DougHauf Don't worry about it. If you Upvote what helps and Accept what helped the most with the specific question, we don't mind. We appreciate the response, too often we don't get any :-)

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I would use NealB's first method for your actual example, and avoid the reference-modification (I think it obscures code, so the next person along has to find out what (3:2) is before they can "read" the code - and the next person may be you in a couple of months), there are other ways.

```
    10  S-CYE   PIC 9(02).
```

Now when you do the MOVE, the compiler will generate code to right-justify and left-truncate. With alphanumeric to alphanumeric you get left-justified right-truncated.

If your source field is "computational" (binary or packed decimal), you can get the "14" from the current year that way.

If the source field happens to be in the order that you require to be shown, and contains the same data (not your example), the whole thing can be done in one shot.

```
01  EDITED-DATE-1 PIC XX/XX/XXXX.
01  EDITED-DATE-2 PIC XXXX/XX/XX.
```

Now when you MOVE a PIC X(8) date to either of the above (depending on where the year is) you'll get the slashes. The Xs in the PIC can be changed to 9 if the source is "computational".

Comment: @JamesAnderson What in particular is unclear to you? I'm happy to expand. If all of it, please indicate, otherwise the particular part or parts you feel are unclear.

Comment: I probably know more COBOL than you, I just the the reference modification is much clearer and requires less COBOL knowledge than messing around with working storage definitions which vary from compiler to compiler.

Comment: Based on what (the probably)? "much clearer" is your opinion, and the "requires less COBOL knowledge" indicates that the clarity your perceive is not to do with COBOL, the language in question. Making COBOL more like something else which does not have COBOL's flexibility of definition is I assume what you mean. Doesn't seem to me that it can be done rigorously enough to have substantial benefit, therefore can only confuse how the COBOL is written (part COBOL, part inefficient and obscure, in COBOL terms). Anyway, this type of exchange is not encouraged. How about putting up your answer?

Answer (score 1):

you can use:
MOVE C-SERVICE-CYE(3:2) TO S-CYE